# How to access Javascript from different domain to local server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-domain

I'm stuck to problem where i'm unable to get control back to local machine.

I have loaded the Iframe where after complete my journey in iframe i want to click my application JS but i'm geting error:

Monthly.js:5 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://xx.xxx.xx.xx" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at window.onload (http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/something/Monthly.js:5:20)

I tried to google many thing but unable to solve this.

I have include HTML file in ASPX page while load.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
     <form id="paypageresponce" runat="server" method="post">
            <!--#include file="Response.html"-->
           <label>Payment in progress...</label>
     </form>

</body>
</html>
```

After load of HTML file i triger Javascript "parent.setPaymentResponseValue(val);" to click on my application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: Hi, i tried the way it mention but this don't work in my case